# Appending two dataframes and filling NANs with values from one of the DFs based on match in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes which i want to append/merge into one (See wanted result in "Wanted result"). I can do this, but rows from Dataframe 2 ends up with NaN in column Name1 and Name2 (see dataframe "My result".

I want the NaN values in my result replaced with values from Dataframe 1, based the number in the Num Column

Dataframe 1:

```
  Num   Name1  Name2   URL
0  1       a      b     url1
1  2       c      d     url2
2  3       e      f     url3
3  4       g      h     url4
```

Dataframe 2:

```
  Num     URL    
0  1      url5
1  2      url6
2  3      url7
3  4      url8
```

Wanted result:

```
  Num   Name1  Name2   URL
0  1       a      b     url1
1  2       c      d     url2
2  3       e      f     url3
3  4       g      h     url4
4  1       a      b     url5
5  2       c      d     url6
6  3       e      f     url7
7  4       g      h     url8
```

My result:

```
     Num   Name1  Name2   URL
   0  1       a      b     url1
   1  2       c      d     url2
   2  3       e      f     url3
   3  4       g      h     url4
   4  1       NaN   NaN    url5
   5  2       NaN   NaN    url6
   6  3       NaN   NaN    url7
   7  4       NaN   NaN    url8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could merge the dataframes:

```
df2.merge(df1[df1.columns[:-1]], on=['Num']).reindex(df1.columns, axis=1)
```

gives:

```
   Num Name1 Name2   URL
0    1     a     b  url5
1    2     c     d  url6
2    3     e     f  url7
3    4     g     h  url8
```

Just concat everything:

```
pd.concat((df1, df2.merge(df1[df1.columns[:-1]], on=['Num']).reindex(df1.columns, axis=1)),
          ignore_index=True)
```

to get as expected:

```
   Num Name1 Name2   URL
0    1     a     b  url1
1    2     c     d  url2
2    3     e     f  url3
3    4     g     h  url4
4    1     a     b  url5
5    2     c     d  url6
6    3     e     f  url7
7    4     g     h  url8
```

Comment: Tried this, but it adds 4 rows for each row from the second dataframe. I can solve it by removing duplicates. It works fine for me, since im dealing with pretty small dataframes anyway. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

We can do `groupby` with `ffill`

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2])
df.fillna(df.groupby('Num').ffill(),inplace=True)
df
Out[43]: 
   Num Name1 Name2   URL
0    1     a     b  url1
1    2     c     d  url2
2    3     e     f  url3
3    4     g     h  url4
0    1     a     b  url5
1    2     c     d  url6
2    3     e     f  url7
3    4     g     h  url8
```

Comment: Is the `fillna()` redundant? Could you just do `df = pd.concat([df1,df2]).groupby('Num').ffill()`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different way:

```
df3 = df.assign(URL = df1['URL']+','+df2['URL'])
df3.assign(URL = df3['URL'].str.split(',')).explode('URL').sort_values('URL')
```